# Array of objects on a json - http put

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have the following Json structure on my project:

```
"disputas": [
    {
      id: "",
      tipo_negociacao: "",
      historico:[{
         fl_usuario: "",
         created_at: "",
         updated_at: "",
         created_by: null,
         updated_by: null,
         texto: "",
      }]
    }
]
```

I want to add a new index of `historico` when I click on a button but don't know how to do it, I want it to look like this:

```
 "disputas": [
        {
          id: "",
          tipo_negociacao: "",
          historico:[{
             fl_usuario: "",
             created_at: "",
             updated_at: "",
             created_by: null,
             updated_by: null,
             texto: "",
          },
           {
             fl_usuario: "",
             created_at: "",
             updated_at: "",
             created_by: null,
             updated_by: null,
             texto: "",
          }

       ]
    }
]
```

So far, I've done something like this (function that the button calls):

```
     recusaProposta() {
        this.disputa.historico[this.i].texto = "something";   
        this.i++;
}
```

now, since `i` starts on `0` this works on the first time I click on the button, but if I click on it again I'll get this error:

> Cannot set property 'texto' of undefined

Can someone help me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just push a new item to the historico array:

```
this.disputa.historico.push({
fl_usuario: "",
             created_at: "",
             updated_at: "",
             created_by: null,
             updated_by: null,
             texto: ""
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You run into the error

> Cannot set property 'texto' of undefined

when you try to access a property on a undefined or null object.

You will first have to create a empty object in its place, if not already existing. 
The way your code is, it is expecting the object to be present in the index you are trying to access.

```
var existingObj = this.disputa.historico[this.i];

// if the value is falsy, then go ahead and create
// an empty object at that index
if(!existingObj) {
   this.disputa.historico[this.i] = {};
}

existingObj.texto = "something";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there are more simple solutions as I discovered now on the other answers, but this one makes sense and has a very nice explanation. Thank you

Comment: @RenêSilvaLima You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Just append an array:

```
this.disputa.historico.push({/* your object here*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
disputas.historico.push({/* obj*/});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15777175)

Comment: @RicardoAlvaroLohmann Link? What link?